# How to find the duplicate entries in sql on day basis

Tags: mysql

```
  id | user_id | date
------------------------
  1     1         2017-09-12
  2     1         2017-09-12
  3     2         2017-09-12
  4     1         2017-09-13
  5     2         2017-09-15
  6     3         2017-09-15
  7     3         2017-09-15
  8     4         2017-09-15
```

Since `1` is duplicated on 2 dates `12 and 13` but need to to consider on 12 itself. if same use id is duplicated any number times but need to consider as `one` entry

Expected out
Query has to print

```
date     count
2017-09-12  2
2017-09-13  1 
2017-09-15  1 #3 duplicated one time
```

My query is working fine with below:

```
SELECT   a.date, count(*) 
FROM table_one a INNER JOIN user b on a.uid = b.id 
WHERE date(a.date) between current_date-3 and current_date  
    GROUP BY 1 HAVING count(*)>1 ORDER BY date
```

Is there any way like:

```
SELECT date,count(*) (SELECT   a.date, count(*) 
  FROM table_one a INNER JOIN user b on a.uid = b.id 
  WHERE date(a.date) between current_date-3 and current_date  
  GROUP BY 1 HAVING count(*)>1 ORDER BY date)a) 
GROUP BY  date
```

Comment: Why isn't the duplicate count 2 for `2017-09-15` since `user_id` 2 was seen on `2017-09-12` as well?

Comment: Can you explain the expected result for `2017-09-15`? Why is it 1 instead of 3?

Comment: it is there total count on 12th is 2(1 and2), on 15th (2 and 3) is already to the date 12th, mean to say if userid 1 is duplicated any number of days it will considered as one.

Comment: 15 has 2, 3, and 4, so shouldn't the count be 3?

Comment: on 15th (only 3 is duplicated), 2 is already added to the date 12th

Comment: I don't understand at all. Are you comparing each date with the previous date in some way?

Comment: yes, example on 12th 1, and 2 is already added, so if 1 and 2 duplicates and date after that it will ignore

Comment: I don't understand the crucial difference between what you have that works, and the 2nd version. Why do you want a different version? Sorry, but I just don't quite understand your question. What you're trying to accomplish differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `constraints` when creating a table, which wouldn't allow you to enter duplicate data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  column1 datatype UNIQUE,
  column2 datatype UNIQUE,
  column3 datatype UNIQUE,
);
....
```

[Learn more](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_constraints.asp) about Constrains

**Or**
you can get that with `DISTINCT`, it'll give a unique value like below

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM table;

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM table;
```

Comment: I think you mean `UNIQUE`?

Comment: He doesn't want to prevent duplication in the table, just count them in some confusing way.

Comment: @Barmar exactly!

Comment: You have broken formatting in your answer. "Learn more" should be a link.